# Compare columns in a table and only show differences

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two columns in the same table that I'm trying to compare. The issue is that they don't have to be identical to be considered "the same". Below I'll try to explain with an example.

Example:

```
HOST_NAME     ENVIRONMENT                  SUBNET_ENVIRONMENT
host1         Production                   Prod
host2         Development(Dev)/Testing     Non-Prod
host3         Development(Dev)             Prod
host4         Production                   Non-Prod
host5         Testing/UAT                  Prod
host6         DR                           Prod
```

Essentially, if the "SUBNET_ENVIRONMENT" is Prod, the ENVIRONMENT should be "Production" as well. If the "SUBNET_ENVIRONMENT" is Non-Prod, the ENVIRONMENT should be anything besides "Production".

In this example, the first two would (host1 and host2) would be considered correct, and therefore be left out of the results. The following 4 (host{3-6}) are "different" so these are the ones that I want to be shown in the results of the query.

Below is a sample query for how I get the entire resultset. How can I modify this to only show the differences?

```
SELECT
   HOST_NAME,
   REPLACE(HOST_ENVIRONMENT,',','/') HOST_ENV,
   HOST_SUBNET_ENV
FROM 
   HOST_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be as simple as an OR:

```
SELECT
   HOST_NAME,
   REPLACE(HOST_ENVIRONMENT,',','/') HOST_ENV,
   HOST_SUBNET_ENV
FROM 
   HOST_TABLE
WHERE (SUBNET_ENVIRONMENT = 'Prod' AND ENVIRONMENT <> 'Production')
OR (SUBNET_ENVIRONMENT = 'Non-Prod' AND ENVIRONMENT = 'Production')
```